# Cannot reach Kali login screen, stuck on "started GNOME Display Manager"

Tags: kali-linux

Ok, so this has started to happen today for no real reason.

I wanted to boot up my Kali build when it got stuck on "[ OK ] Started GNOME Display Manager"

Weird thing is, the mouse appears. Like if I was in the actual login screen.
I can move the mouse, type, I've even tried to login. 
I feel like the OS did start, it's just that the screen doesn't change (oh and yes, recovery mode works. I might try to start another version or try to see the logs).

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem. It happened yesterday, at the same moment as you, and i think that's a bad upgrade of gmd3 (Gnome Display Manager 3), beacause i reset my pc to despair, and i have install Kali Linux. When i restart my Pc after the update, it did exactly the same error. I think that we should wait a new update that repair Gnome, and do

> sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get upgrade;sudo apt autoremove;reboot

when a new update is avalible in the recovery mode. It's my opinion, but i don't really know what's happening.

I did a

> sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get upgrade

today, and it did an update of gdm3, but it repair anything :(

I'm trying to install another desktop environnement, but i can't do it. So i'm just using Windows 10, waiting an update.

I don't think that i helped someone, but i want share my situation. Sorry for my basic english, i'm not a native speaker. (I sometimes uses a translator)(Google lol)

So if someone has an idea faster than Offencive Security (the Kali dev), please tell our the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Currently, this is a bug of Gnome.

Install lightdm with `apt install lightdm` as [suggested by kali admins](https://bugs.kali.org/view.php?id=5727).

Answer (score 0):

I just realized I had the same problem. Not sure why it happened since I just fixed, but it seemed to be in my case a problem with lack of space in the partitions of my hard drive. When installing linux (kali) I partitioned the hard drive for each individual folder, (so /root had its own partition and so /usr, etc) which is not the recommended way.
so to solve it I went into the virtual console(Recovery Mode), and ran:

**sudo apt-get autoclean**

**sudo apt-get autoremove**

and it worked! Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

probably your kali partition storage is full you should boot from live kali usb then resize it with gparted.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ apt --fix-broken install
```

This solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice solution to solve this issue.

Just press <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> before the boot process ends and gets stuck with "started GNOME Display Manager".

If you try to switch terminal when boot process is finished, it's too late and nothing is happening.